# Spring Boot 405 POST method not supported?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How could POST method not support by Spring Boot MVC ?! I am trying to implement a simple post method that accepts a list of entities : here is my code

```
@RestController(value="/backoffice/tags")
public class TagsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public void add(@RequestBody List<Tag> keywords) {
            tagsService.add(keywords);
        }
}
```

Hitting this URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8090/backoffice/tags/add
```

Request Body:

```
[{"tagName":"qweqwe"},{"tagName":"zxczxczx"}]
```

I receive:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1441800482010,
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
    "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
    "path": "/backoffice/tags/add"
}
```

**EDIT**:

Debugging Spring Web Request Handler

```
     public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            this.checkRequest(request); 

 protected final void checkRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        String method = request.getMethod();
        if(this.supportedMethods != null && !this.supportedMethods.contains(method)) {
            throw new HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException(method, StringUtils.toStringArray(this.supportedMethods));
        } else if(this.requireSession && request.getSession(false) == null) {
            throw new HttpSessionRequiredException("Pre-existing session required but none found");
        }
    }
```

The only two methods in `supportedMethods` are `{GET,HEAD}`

Comment: Update the code of TagsController as well.

Comment: Consider rolling back to revision 2. Right now, the code in your question is correct, making the answer meaningless.

Comment: @RafalG. the code in question is not supposed to be "fixed", it breaks the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have an error in RestController annotation definition. According to the docs it is:

> public @interface RestController {
>
> /**      * The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component
>   name,      * to be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected
>   component.     * @return the suggested component name, if any      * @since
>   4.0.1      */     String value() default "";
>
> }

Which means the value you have entered ("/backoffice/tags") is NAME of the controller not the path under which it is available.

Add `@RequestMapping("/backoffice/tags")` on the controller's class and remove value from the `@RestController` annotation.

**EDIT:**
Fully working example as per comment that it does not work - try to use this code please - and run locally from IDE.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' 

jar {
    baseName = 'demo'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") 
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

**Tag.java**

```
package demo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Tag {

    private final String tagName;

    @JsonCreator
    public Tag(@JsonProperty("tagName") String tagName) {
        this.tagName = tagName;
    }

    public String getTagName() {
        return tagName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Tag{");
        sb.append("tagName='").append(tagName).append('\'');
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**SampleController.java**

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/backoffice/tags")
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void add(@RequestBody List<Tag> tags) {
        System.out.println(tags);
    }
}
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that is one but it still not working ... even after changing it

Comment: Let me reproduce it. Gimme 5 mins.

Answer (score 3):

Actually When method name is available but method type is different than required type so this exception will throw 405.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same kind of error when I was developing. Please check the URL path is correctly mapped with the same as you are checking. Hope it resolves the problem.