# Post API call shows Method not allowed

Tags: java, angular, spring, rest

I am getting following error while calling post API.

> 405 Method Not Allowed

From angular i am calling post API like following.

```
private createFormUrl = `api/form/add`

public createForm(form: Form): Observable<string> {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.createFormUrl, form)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

API in JAVA

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping( value = "/api/form")
public class FormManagementController {

private FormManagementService formmanagementService;

@PostMapping(path = "/add",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createForm(@RequestBody(required = false) Form form) {
        String respond = formmanagementService.createForm(form);
        return ResponseEntity.status(getProperHttpStatus(respond)).build();
    }
```

**Error:**

**URL:** http://localhost/api/form/add (Working in postman)

[image]

I checked but, GET is not written any where for this API.

I checked many posts on stackoverflow but, nothing work for me. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in Postman collection to ensure its working

So you can isolate its a angular specific issue, You didn't share the request payload. If not workign in post man alos then make code changes.

Instead of @PostMapping try this @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)

Full example Ref : [Spring Boot 405 POST method not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479919/spring-boot-405-post-method-not-supported)

Comment: `@RequestMapping("/backoffice/tags")` it's already there. Please check my question again.

Comment: Tried but, no luck. :(

Comment: Get rid of @Consumes and produces as well. Make use annotation RequestMapping instead of postmapping Ref accepted answer in this URL for a full example similar issue 405 not allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706078/put-and-post-getting-405-method-not-allowed-error-for-restful-web-services?rq=1

Comment: Whether getting rid of @consumes solved the issue ? If not share, the JSON request payload as well.

Comment: what is the request JSON which you are passing

Comment: `{
 "title": "test",
 "description": "test",
 "event": {
  "location": "place",
  "details": "test",
  "capacity": 10,
  "startDateTime": null,
  "endDateTime": null,
  "publishDateTime": null
 }
}`

Comment: In one Project there are two container/module/service. Angular code in 1 module and Java API in another moudle/service.

Comment: Try to pass the headers in your angular code Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032465/angular2-http-post-headers/35032846#35032846 . which angular version you are using

Comment: I am using angular version 7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE** to get the media type string value.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/add",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry but, no luck :(

Comment: @ketan Same error? Do you have any end-point working? Are you setting the content-type header when doing the request? Have you tried removing the requestbody parameter for testing?

Answer (score 0):

You better try with 'application/json' rather than MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
Not to defame anything, again. But there seems to be much topics upon the net about what should be used as the JSON MIME type.

The spec lists clearly only one MIME media type for JSON and it is "application/json" (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627, section "6. IANA Considerations".

Just give a shot with the MIME type as 'application/json' in both consumes and produces.

@Robert

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that the response headers do not indicate that `POST` is allowed. The allow methods header should return something like `GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD`'. Please add an attribute to the controller like so: `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", methods= "*")`. `methods` is the property which will set the response header that lists which methods are allowed. Only browsers enforce CORS. Postman, curl don't enforce CORS. So, errors such as these are not evident at first glance. Hope that helps.